# How does Stack Overflow manage notifications and templates?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, design, architecture, technology

Each Stack Exchange site has the same kind of style. How are these styles maintained in a uniform fashion? Is there some sort of base template that each site shares and overrides as necessary?

And similarly, how does each site implement the notification system? Is each site responsible for implementing it, or is there an underlying framework that is utilized?

I'm gearing up to implement a system that has base functionality shared across multiple sites, so I'm very interested to hear how it's been done before.

Comment: Through the trademarked _StackExchange™ MultiCollider Dropdown™_!

Comment: Related, although not duplicate: [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369)

Comment: @Cole Because it doesn't contain the answer to this question, and I'm not sure that it should. It is more general information, this is asking something specific about the site's architecture. Knowing the name of a tool or technology used to create it (e.g. C# and ASP.NET) is insufficient.

Comment: I don't see how this is unclear. Even as a downvote enthusiast, I'm at a loss to explain why it currently has a score of -3. It seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me. My only thought was whether it would be better asked on the main site since it is programming-related, but I decided against that since it is otherwise too open-ended unless contextualized to "how did the SE team do this?". @cole

Comment: @CodyGray well, out of sympathy, I changed it to -2 :)

Comment: Code reuse! Works in practice, b*tches! (no offense intended)

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah my intention was to see how SE implemented it.  It's kind of an open-ended question so I wanted to add some context.  Unfortunately the "Tools and technologies used to build SE" question doesn't get me the details I need.  It's nice to know we share the same code stack (WISC) though :)